# Send me away with the words of a love song

Tags: articles

I came across this beautiful [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NJqUN9TClM) by The Band Perry.
Can somebody please tell me how native English speakers would understand the meaning of this line?

> Send me away with the words of a love song

The definite article in "the words" is used here to mean ALL the words (lyrics) of a song? Or does it imply some specific words?

The indefinite article in "a love song" means it can be any love song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in literal terms it means specific words of any love song, as you have mentioned of the indefinite and definite articles being used.

The real message of the entire song becomes clear when she laments the fact that her life-long message of love and understanding will be heard much more clearly now that she's gone.

It seems this line was intended to generalise this point of words in a love song.